# Is it good practice to open a new browser for every test case? (Selenium, JUnit)

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I am using Selenium and JUnit for testing. First time doing testing, so I'm not sure what the best practices are.

For every single test case, do I need to open a new browser or do I set it up so that one test case can pick up where the previous test case left off, and use the browser state of the previous test case? Are there some general rules of thumb for this?

Initially I was thinking that opening a new browser for every test case would be too inefficient so I was trying to have the test cases run one after the other, but run order cannot be assigned in JUnit.  So now I am thinking that I need to make every test case completely independent and have some "set up" lines of code at the beginning of each test case and if applicable use `@Before`.

Is a good way to do it?

1. In `setUpBeforeClass(){}` create the browser
2. Use `driver.get("specific url for test case");` at beginning of every test case. But this would be bad when changing between environments and changing urls.....

Answer (score 0):

You can save time by just deleting cookies between tests with:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: And this would allow me to use the same browser, but for the next test case I would still need to navigate to the correct/needed web page?

Comment: If a particular test case needs to navigate to a particular place before it runs its assert, is it ok to use other test cases inside of this test case to get to that correct place in the browser, and then check the asserts of the test case? That way code isn't being re-written. What is a good way to handle these situations where a test case is run "deep" in the website, and each test case is set up to start fresh?

Comment: That's a different question :)

Comment: @Alex if you want to test behaviour on other pages after adding something on an other one you should think about navigation on page - assert it is "normal" - persist something by code - reload page.
1 Test should be test just 1 page.